# jquery drag and drop clone

Tags: jquery, drag-and-drop

i am using following code

```
var $albumcover = $('#albumcover');
<br>
$albumcover.droppable({
<br>
accept: '#trash2 li',
<br>
activeClass: 'ui-state-highlight',
drop: function(ev, ui) {
<br>
$(this).append($(ui.draggable).clone().attr('alt', 'nat'));
<br>
 $(this).find('img').css('width','100px');
<br>
$(this).find('img').css('height','100px');

}
});
```

how can i

add events to clone element when it's created so it should be drag able again...

Comment: Question should be rephrased. Right now it's more of a forum post than a question.

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
$(this).append($(ui.draggable).clone().attr('alt', 'nat'));
```

with

```
$(this).append($(ui.draggable).clone(true).attr('alt', 'nat'));
```

The true value is used to

Clone matched DOM Elements, and all their event handlers, and select the clones.

Read the doc

[clone( bool )](http://docs.jquery.com/Manipulation/clone)